# RSA Signature Attack without Valid Message and Signature Pairs

Tags: rsa, signature, forgery

I know about the existential forgery attack on RSA where a forgery is possible given two valid message and signature pairs but I am wondering how can a forgery be done on RSA with just the knowledge of the public key (e and n) without the knowledge of another message/signature pair given that the signatures are not padded?

Comment: Hint: what exactly is an existential forgery? With that written, how do you make these? Note: We don't even need $n$ or $e$ to make one, or even two existential forgeries. With $n$ alone. we can make a third (and we don't even need pencil and paper). If we could factor $n$ into the product of two distinct primes, we could make nine existential forgeries (but in RSA, adversaries can't factor $n$). With $(n,e)$, we can make as many existential forgeries as $n$ and our patience allows.

Comment: Would it be just an attack where we sign the message with a random number r and then divide the signature/r (the blinding attack)?

Comment: Developing: An Existential Forgery is any (message,signature) pair $(m,s)$ that pass the test made by the verifier against the public key $(e,n)$. In one definition of textbook RSA signature, that test is: $0\le m<n$ and $0\le s<n$ and $s^e\bmod n=m$. Again, one can make two EFs without even knowing $n$, an additional EF knowing $n$ (and that $e$ is odd in RSA), and six additional EFs if  knowing a factorization of $n$ as $n=pq$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$. With knowledge of $(e,n)$, we can make as many EFs as $n$ allows.

Comment: So could an attacker create a random signature $s$ and based on that generate a message such that message = Encryption($s$) = $s^e\bmod n$?

Comment: Yes! Alternatively, without $n$, $(m,s)=(0,0)$ and $=(1,1)$ are valid EFs. So is $(n-1,n-1)$. And more generally the nine $(m,m)$ with $m\bmod p\in\{0,1,p-1\}$ and $m\bmod q\in\{0,1,q-1\}$, assuming $n=p\,q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$.